# What is the name of the complement of a nowhere dense set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, terminology

Let $A$ be a nowhere dense set, what is the name of $A^c$? It seems much stronger than the definition of dense set. I think if we assume $A$ is a close set, then $A$ is nowhere dense iff $A^c$ is dense. But what about the general case?

---

I found a long name for this: a dense set with dense interior. Does there exist a fancier name, probably named after a person?

Comment: Is “everywhere dense” what you’re looking for?

Comment: @MPW I think everywhere dense is equivalent to "dense", which is weaker than the notion of "a set with dense interior"

Comment: I've heard "co-nowhere dense" in a talk, but I don't think that's common terminology.

Comment: @Henning Makholm has already given a nice answer, but for what it's worth, in differential geometry I've often seen the term "*generic*" used for "open and dense" (and perhaps more generally, "superset of open and dense", although I think nearly all cases of any interest are open and dense), which equals the complement of "closed and nowhere dense" (complement of a subset of "closed and nowhere dense", in the case of the more general superset case). I've also seen "generic" used (even in the title of a paper) to mean "an arbitrarily chosen element" of a set.

Comment: Incidentally, there are stronger notions of density than what "complement of nowhere dense" gives you, namely notions that involve being the complement of a porous set (there are many different notions of this), and some authors use the term "plump set" for the corresponding open sets that these porous sets are the complements of. For example, see the google search ["plump" + "uniform domain"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22plump%22+%22uniform+domain%22).

Comment: Regarding my first comment above, just two days later I happened to see a [Stack Exchange question in which "generic set" is used to mean an arbitrarily chosen set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2936973/capacity-and-hausdorff-measure).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nowhere dense set is one whose closure has an empty interior.

Therefore the *complement* of a nowhere dense set is one whose *interior* has a *closure* that is the entire space.

Or, in other words, a set whose interior is dense.

Or, in yet other words, a **superset of a dense open set**.

Answer (score 1):

[Generic set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_property) is sort of usual. See the topology section of the linked page. But in Baire spaces this name is also used for co-meagre sets. I personally like generic set.

Comment: I agree. However it is not precise because the superset of a dense open set is stronger than "generic" which is usually just dense open set.